# What is causing my Uncaught TypeError in my each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm working on returning a list of Id's that will be used to filter data in a Kendoui Grid.  The Id's are returned using Ajax from a controller in my MVC application, the function is then supposed to loop through the returned object and, using filters, update the datasource accordingly.

Whilst I can get results from the object I also get an error which causes the function to stop.  The error is of:

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 5
```

I've tried using `JSON.parse` but that didn't work.  My code is as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetTabs")",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'Name' : 'John' },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            tabInfo(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR.status);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

function tabInfo(e) {
        let filters = [];
        let tags = $("#tags");
        let grid = $("#CarGrid");

        var idFilter = {
            logic: "or",
            filters: []
        };

        $.each(e, function (index, value) {
            $.each(value, function (_, d) {
                idFilter.filters.push({
                    field: "Id",
                    operator: "eq",
                    value: d.Id
                    })
                filters.push(idFilter);
            })
        });
        grid.dataSource.filter({
            logic: "and",
            filters: filters
        });
    }
```

When I searched online, I saw many posts stating that it was because you need to parse the data returned, I attempted to do that but got the same result in the end.  I can see that it returns the results but then hits this error shortly after.

**Update**

Ajax Response is:

```
{Data: Array(5), Total: 5, AggregateResults: null, Errors: null}
AggregateResults
:
null
Data
:
Array(5)
0 : {Id: 1, TabName: "Test Tab", UserName: "John", UserEmail: "John", CreatedAt: "/Date(1530867600000)/", …}
1 : {Id: 2, TabName: "Test Tab 2", UserName: "John", UserEmail: "John", CreatedAt: "/Date(1530873780000)/", …}
2 : {Id: 3, TabName: "Test Tab 3", UserName: "John", UserEmail: "John", CreatedAt: "/Date(1530874140000)/", …}
3 : {Id: 4, TabName: "Test Tab 4", UserName: "John", UserEmail: "John", CreatedAt: "/Date(1530874260000)/", …}
4 : {Id: 5, TabName: "Test Tab 5", UserName: "John", UserEmail: "John", CreatedAt: "/Date(1530874320000)/", …}
length : 5
__proto__ : Array(0)
Errors : null
Total : 5
```

Is my use of two each loops to extract data incorrect?

Comment: What is your AJAX response?

Comment: How is your data structured / how does it look ?

Comment: Please build an [mcve]

Comment: It seems your use of the jqeury API is  incorrect - try `$(e).each(function ...` instead  of `$.each(e, function ...` (same for the inner iteration over `value`). Btw, why are you using the jquery iterator at all? `e.forEach ( ( item, index ) => { ... } );` should work fine. If you know that you'll receive data from the ajax all as json, you may replace `$.ajax` by `$.getJSON`.

Comment: @collapsar if @yanayaya use `$(e).each(function ...` then it is incorrect, `$(e).each` is used to iterate over a collection of DOM elements and @yanayaya is trying to iterate over an array, so, using `$.each(e, function ...` is correct but instead using `Array.prototype.forEach` is enough

Comment: @CastroRoy: It seems that both syntaxes are supported, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/5tqu41pr/5/)'s  output. Note that jquery constructor `$` may be applied to other objects than dom nodes. I stand corrected, however, about the false assertion in my previous comment(s), which I shall delete.

Comment: @collapsar you are right, both syntaxes are supported, take a look also at [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), but, there is no need to use the `jquery` constructor on an array like `$([1, 2, 3])`, I don't see an use case for this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your ajax response, I think you do not need two `$.each` and instead just iterate over `response.Data`, this should be enough

```
$.each(e.Data, function (_, d) {
    idFilter.filters.push({
        field: "Id",
        operator: "eq",
        value: d.Id
        })
    filters.push(idFilter);
});
```

Now, as @collapsar's commented, you don't need to use `$.each` if what we get in the response is an `Array`, this should work too but using `Array.prototype.forEach`

```
e.Data.forEach(function (d) {
    idFilter.filters.push({
        field: "Id",
        operator: "eq",
        value: d.Id
        })
    filters.push(idFilter);
});
```

Hope it helps